# Finding distance/similarity function between two vectors in a multi-dimensional space, with weighted components/dimensions

Tags: maximum-likelihood, distance, similarities

I have a multi-dimensional space with $d$ dimensions wherein $i$ vectors ($v_1 ... v_i$) with $d$ components live. I want to find a function $s(v_a, v_b)$ which takes in two of these vectors and outputs a value representing the *similarity* of two vectors. Since the vectors live in a space, this function should be a function measuring the *distance* between these vectors.

In my real life problem, each vector in the space represents an *event* (or *situation*). The components of the vector store *characteristics/parameters/features* of the situation.

A straightforward answer would be to calculate the Euclidean distance between the two vectors: $s(v_a, v_b) = || v_a - v_b||$.

This is perfectly fine for my problem, however, **every component (or dimension in the space) should be *weighted* differently when calculating the distance between the two vectors)**. So, in other words: since every component of the vector conveys a real-life characteristic (for example: temperature in degrees centigrade, distance in meters, whatever), each of these components (or characteristics of the event described by the vector) has a different degree of *importance* or *salience* when compared with another situation.

So, the final formula could become a dot product: $s(v_a, v_b) =  w \cdot | v_a - v_b|$ ; where $w$ is a vector of $d$ components containing the weights for every dimension/component/feature/characteristic. I guess this will become something like a *Mahalanobis distance* (?)

My big question is: **how to can I learn these weights?**

Now, I came up with an answer myself, but I am not quite sure if I am thinking in the right direction. My approach would be as follows: I can create some kind of *outcome* value for every of the millions of vectors I have - there will be a couple hundred different 'outcome values'. Let's say I have $m$ different outcomes. For every group of vectors with the same outcome I know that all vectors in that group, when compared with each other (so, with members of the same group of vectors), the *similarity function $s(v_a, v_b)$ should return the maximum value*, since I assume them (for now) to be situations with identical outcomes. Now, for every dimension $d$ I will calculate the mean (just the simple average) of all values for $d$ in the vectors in that group. I will then end up with $m$ mean values for every $d$. For every $d$, I can perform MLE to fit a Gaussian (or another suitable distribution) to the means, and find a value for the variance. These variance values could be the components of my $w$, since: the more the means among different groups of different situations differ from each other, the more useful this dimension/component is to distinct vectors from each other (or in other words: the more this dimension *matters* when comparing two vectors with each other).

To make things even more complicated (please, if someone has anything useful to teach me on my main question, don't hesitate...): it could be that the $w_d$-weight values for two certain dimensions are very low, or in other words: *these features/characteristics do not really matter*, but, if these two dimensions have certain types of values (I mean values for the actual components of the vectors itself, *not* the weights, we in this case already know the weight values are low) (for example: a low value and a high value, two low values, or two high values - this depends on the pair), their combined weight should become *super large*, so, certain values appearing for two dimensions with low weights *simultaneously* means that these dimensions are of *very high importance* when comparing two vectors. My thoughts on this: I could define a matrix, and for every pair of dimensions $d$ I can define a correlation, and these correlations should again be weighted, similar like I mentioned earlier.